# Удаление из таблицы строк с повторящюимися данными

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь удалить из таблицы все строки с повторяющимися значениями в столбце `id`. Нашел в документации, что сделать это можно с помощью запроса вида:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE cards ADD PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

Несмотря на присутствие в запросе ключевого слова `IGNORE`, *phpmyadmin* все равно выдает ошибку `duplicate entry`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нет ли у вас идей, почему не работает?

Comment: Он не избавит вашу таблицу от одинаковых id.
А предотвратит такое в дальнейшем. Все конфликты, что есть вы должны устранить сами, а после делать данную команду.

Comment: Секундочку, @Makarenko_I_V! Но в [доках](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) сказано *If IGNORE is specified, only one row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted*. Т.е. должна удалить.

Comment: Не те доки читаете, может быть? `As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.` Укажите версию вашего сервера.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Хм... У меня верия 5.5.42-37.1 :(((
Нашел в разделе 5.5 объяснение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[добавьте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753520/4827341) временный первично-ключевой столбец с авто-инкрементом (он сразу и наполнится уникальными значениями), а затем, как в [этом примере](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28266100/4827341), удалите дублирующиеся (по стобцу `id`) строки.

потом можно удалить уже ненужный временный столбец и назначить стобец `id` первичным ключом.

результат — в первом запросе, описание таблицы — во втором:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/695c8/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (id int);

insert into t values
  (1),
  (1),
  (2),
  (2),
  (2),
  (3);

alter table t add id2 int not null auto_increment primary key;

delete t1 from t t1, t t2
where t1.id2 < t2.id2
  and t1.id = t2.id;

alter table t drop id2;

alter table t add primary key (id);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/695c8/1/0)**:

```
| id |
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
describe t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/695c8/1/1)**:

```
| COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_TYPE | IS_NULLABLE | COLUMN_KEY | COLUMN_DEFAULT | EXTRA |
|-------------|-------------|-------------|------------|----------------|-------|
|          id |     int(11) |          NO |        PRI |              0 |       |
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось! :)

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается, я смотрел документацию не на ту версию. Я привел ссылку на доки версии 5.1, а у меня сервер версии 5.5.

[Описание в этой части по версии 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) имеют следующий вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, эта фича работает не во всем версиях и мне следует подумать либо о применении `SET SESSION old_alter_table=1` либо о других сособах удаления лишних строк.

Comment: вот решение [«в лоб»](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28266100/4827341), но, зато, по-моему, довольно лаконичное и универсальное. впрочем, посмотрите и на другие ответы к тому вопросу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, боюсь топикстартер может не осилить идею, т.к. в примере id уникален.

Comment: ну да, надо [таким, например, столбцом](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14753520/4827341) дополнить таблицу.

Comment: @artoodetoo, [нарисовал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437616/178576) предлагаемое решение.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо удалять лишние строки самому. А так как там наверное не только id, но и какие-то *осмысленные данные*, то это может быть нетривиальной задачей.

В таблице есть что-то, что было **уникально** до сих пор? Вы можете положиться на это поле/комбинацию полей чтобы  сделать так:

```
DELETE FROM cards
WHERE my_unique_field NOT IN(
  SELECT MIN(c2.my_unique_field)
  FROM cards AS c2
  GROUP BY c2.id
)
```

Благодаря группировке, каждый id будет упоминаться только один раз. Лишнее удалится. После можно делать ALTER TABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY.